# Dispatcher with Node JS

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to do a simple server answering to url /page1 and /page2;
this is the module dispatcher.js:

```
var HttpDispatcher = function() {


this.listeners = { get: [ ], post: [ ] }; 
  this.errorListener = function() { } 
} 

HttpDispatcher.prototype.on = function(method, url, cb) {

  this.listeners[method].push({
    cb: cb,
    url: url 
  }); 
}

HttpDispatcher.prototype.onGet = function(url, cb) {
  this.on('get', url, cb); 
}

HttpDispatcher.prototype.onPost = function(url, cb) {
  this.on('post', url, cb); 
}

HttpDispatcher.prototype.onError = function(cb) {
  this.errorListener = cb; 
}

HttpDispatcher.prototype.dispatch = function(req, res) {

  var parsedUrl = require('url').parse(req.url, true);
  var method = req.method.toLowerCase();

  if(this.listener[method][parsedUrl.pathname]) this.listener[method][parsedUrl.pathname](req, res)
  else this.errorListener(req, res); 
}

module.exports = new HttpDispatcher();
```

and this is the server:

```
var dispatcher = require('./node_modules/httpdispatcher');
var http = require('http');

dispatcher.onGet("/page1", function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Page One'); 
}); 

dispatcher.onPost("/page2", function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Page Two'); 
}); 

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  dispatcher.dispatch(req, res);
}).listen(80, '127.0.0.1');
```

But when i try to execute the server, i get the error:

> D:\Works\Web Resources\NODE JS\node_modules\httpdispatcher.js:33
>   if(this.listener[method][parsedUrl.pathname])
>   this.listener[method][parsedUr
>                     ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be a typo

```
if(this.listener[method][parsedUrl.pathname]) this.listener[method][parsedUrl.pathname](req, res)
```

I think it is `this.listeners` (with -s)

---

2nd question (from comments):

```
HttpDispatcher.prototype.on = function(method, url, cb) {
  this.listeners[method][url] = cb;
}
```

That way, you can check if URL exists (like you already do), and access the function like you already do.

Comment: Yes, it was; but is still not working; now i don't get errors, but while the server running, if i request a URL, ex 127.0.0.1/page1, i get no answer...

Comment: try setting severals `console.log` so that you can check where your server is going (or where it is not going)

Comment: It seems that the dispatch function is always calling the ErrorListener even if you request a valid URL like /page1